# Shell environment variables

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I'm trying to add a directory to my PATH environment so I can run some commands remotely. I have set this in my `.bashrc`, `.tcshrc` as well as in `/etc/profile` and `/etc/csh.login` but whenever I check my path remotely via SSH it is not in my path. When I log in, from the shell I have

```
>/usr/bin/env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/path/I/just/added
```

but remotely:

> SSH hostname "/usr/bin/env| grep PATH"
>       PATH=/usr/bin

I seem to remember something about a difference between login shells and interactive shells. Where do I set environment variables so they hold for all shells.

Answer (score 4):

1. Change `PermitUserEnvironment` to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
   and restart sshd.
2. Define a PATH in `/home/user/.ssh/environment` on the ssh server, e.g.

   ```
   PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin
   ```

Comment: That worked. Don't have enough reputation points to vote up your answer so thanks is all I have for now.

Comment: @JavaDev: If an answer has solved your problem, [mark it as accepted](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask).